# OAuth Approval Page won't fit on iPhone 4

Tags: yammer

The page used to give approval to a third pary app at https://www.yammer.com//dialog/oauth is called when using the Log In With Yammer button.

When viewed on an iPhone 4 screen the Approve and Deny buttons are off the bottom of the screen, and the page isn't scrollable, so you can never get to them.

Are we missing something, or is this process completely impossible in a browser of that resolution. Any workarounds ?

Answer (score 0):

We have encountered the same issue on a recent project that uses Yammer as an oAuth provider and small screen heights can not click the approve button.

We have opted to use JavaScript client detection to send a custom browser message to these users, the custom message advises users to visit the page from their desktop on a one time only basis.

The next time they visit the page from their mobile device they will be authed and will be able to get past the next stage.

The lowest sized screen that could still auth on Yammer natively had a window.height of 460 hence the solution below to notify these users:

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
       if (jQuery(window).height() < 460) {
       jQuery('#wpoa-title').html("**IMPORTANT:**      ");
  }
});